# Windows 10 load dll the non admin way

Tags: java, windows, dllimport, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application where we load a dll through System.loadLibrary(). In Windows 10, if the RCP application is run as administrator, then dll gains admin privileges. Is there a way where i can load this dll without admin rights ? Any help on this ?

Answer (score 2):

DLLs do not have privileges, neither admin or otherwise. Rights are granted to the process. All code that runs in that process has the same rights. So once a process has admin rights, all code in that process has those rights. When you load a DLL you load code into a process. The system has no mechanism to give that module's code different rights.

So, if you want to execute code with different rights, you should execute the code in a separate process without admin rights.